# Anyway to install stable Softwares in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-installation, 14.10, software-sources

Is there anyway i can install stable version of softwares on Ubuntu 14.10? 
Because software that we install on Ubuntu 14.10 all of them are in Pre-release state like if i install vlc from software center or from terminal it will be in RC stage means unstable.
Is there anyway i can configure my repositories to download stable version of required software?

Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 was released in October last year. From that point on it wasn't considered a release candidate any more and its packages became stable. Do you have a particular reason why you want to go back to previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

As [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) said in his comment, why do you want to install previous versions?  In the case of you question regarding stable installation, here is how to install stable vlc.

To install stable VLC, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I don't want to go to previous versions. I want to go to Stable versions. The version of vlc in Ubuntu 14.10 is "2.2.0-pre2 weatherwax" which is pretty much unstable and so do other softwares like Smplayer, audacious etc

Comment: I've added the stable respository and removed vlc then i reinstalled by typing "sudo apt-get install vlc" and i'm getting this version:

http://s21.postimg.org/85597fz8n/Screenshot_from_2015_01_04_20_28_00.png

Answer (score 0):

Check your software & Update settings, it sounds like you have a checkmark in the Pre-Release option. Try unchecking that option.